# Some outlets seem to have no power

Tags: electrical

I have electricity in my bathroom and kitchen and even my porch light and security light outside is on, but there are no numbers on my meter box. What could b the cause of this? There are 2 outlets that work but nowhere else--not even in the kitchen where there is electricity.

Comment: Sounds more confusing than weird.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "no numbers on your meter box"?

Comment: You're not seeing any numbers on the display of your smart meter?  Many of them display nothing at all until you imteract with them in some way.  You have to wake up the display.

Comment: Reset all the breakers in your panel including the main.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have tripped a Arc Fault Interrupt Circuit - a safety feature to prevent electrocution in modern homes. Try turning off all the switches on your breaker box and turning them on again or try looking for a switch which is slightly raised from the other like pictured here:

[image: Arc Fault Interrupt]

You might also notice a little window with an orange, blue or green indicator or a raised button similar to one of these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This switch will need to be turned off and on again to reset the circuit and restore power to the outlets.

Comment: AFCI devices are not intended to prevent electrocution, they are designed to prevent fires due to arcing faults. Ground-fault circuit interrupters (GFCI), are designed to prevent electrocution. While dual function circuit interrupters (DFCI), are designed to prevent both.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok so I have electricity in my bathroom and kitchen and even my porch light and security light outside is on..but there is no numbers on my meter box..what could b the cause of this...there is 2 outlets that work but no where else not even in the kitchen where there is electricity..

I'd suggest rewording your post as it's a bit confusing to understand.. however.. since there has already been mention of an AFCI breaker, I'll hook on to the other issue I see and go from there. You said...

> ..but there is no numbers on my meter box..

Do you mean your electric meter mounted somewhere on the outside of your house? If it is not displaying any numbers, then it is an issue directly related to itself or between the utility and your house. Since some electrical is still working, it sounds like you've lost a main line, but still have the other and your neutral intact. Contact your power company, they will be able to see what's up with the meter.

[image: Electric meter]